# About Example 1 in Section 28 of Munkres's topology

Tags: general-topology

In Section 28(Limit Point Compactness) of Munkres's Topology, the Example 1 states the following:

> Let $Y=\{0, 1\}$ given the trivial topology, and $\mathbb{Z_+}$ be given the discrete topology. Then, the space $X:=\mathbb{Z_+}\times Y$ is limit point compact, for every nonempty subset of $X$ has a limit point. $\cdots$

The term limit point compact means the following:

> A space $X$ is said to be limit point compact if every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point.

I was trying to prove this seemingly very easy example in class. In order to show that $X$ is limit point compact, we need to show that any infinite subset has a limit point. Take an infinite subset $B\subset \mathbb{Z_+}\times Y$, and take a point $(b, t)\in \mathbb{Z_+}\times Y$. Consider the point $(b', t)$ for $b\neq b'$. My professor claims that any neighborhood of $(b', t)$ contains $(b, t)$. I know that an open set of $X$ looks like $A\times Y$ or $A\times \emptyset=\emptyset$. However I fail to see where the fact that $B$ is infinite comes to work.

I think my topological base is very wobbly, so I could use any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B\subset \mathbb{Z_+}\times Y$

Suppose $B$ is non empty.

$B=C\times D$ where $C\subset \mathbb{Z_+}$ and $D\subset Y$

Let, $x\in C$ .

Claim: $(x, 0) \in B$ is a limit point of $B$ .

Choose any open set $U\subset \mathbb{Z_+}\times Y$ containing $(x,0)$ .

Since any nonempty open set of $Y$ is  $Y$ itself, $U=V \times Y$ where $V \subset \mathbb{Z_+} $ is an open set containing $x$.

Then $(x, 1) \in U\setminus \{(x,0)\}$

Hence, $(x, 0) \in B $ is a limit point of $B$.

Hence any non-empty subset of $\mathbb{Z_+}\times Y$  contains a limit point.

To prove limit point Compactness , we need to show that every infinite subset has a limit point but it doesn't force us to consider a finite set doesn't have a limit point in itself.

It may happen in a non $T_1$- space and the given product topology on $\mathbb{Z_+}\times Y$ is a non $T_1$- space $\big[$Choose two distinct points $(1, 0) $ and $(1, 1) \big]$

Comment: Sorry I couldn't check it as sooner as possible. I get that any point $(x, 0)$ is a limit point of $B$, finite or infinite. Then, in the original problem, are the points $(b, t)$ and $(b', t)$ in the same neighborhood? Also, I'm not sure if I got your last sentence right. So $Y$ is non $T_1$, and $\mathbb{Z_+}\times Y$ is also non $T_1$, but where does this lead us to?

Comment: Well. Ignore the last part.I mean in a $T_1$ space, a finite set can't contain a limit point . As any open set containing a limit point must be infinite.

Comment: But in a $T_1$ space, every finite set is closed, so it contains its limit point, isn't it? I think I'm messing up somewhere.

Comment: It's trivial as the set of all limit points in empty set. It may not have a limit point at all.

Comment: Oh...I think I get it. Thanks for clearing things up. I get messed up with all these terminologies.